# upload files dynamically to user folders

Tags: uploads

we have several users on our site. we have created a separate folder for each user. Admin have a select box to select users on the site. we have to give ability to upload files to that particular user on selection.

I have created a hook to upload_dir. its working fine with the logged in user. but how to make it dynamic on admin panel. How make this work when admin selected an user in drop down menu and upload files to that user he selected.

```
    function custom_upload_directory( $args ) {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $base_directory = ABSPATH."user_documents/".$current_user->user_login;
        $base_url = home_url()."/user_documents/".$current_user->user_login;
        $args['path'] = $base_directory;
        $args['url']  = $base_url;
        $args['subdir'] = $current_user->user_login;
        $args['basedir'] = $base_directory;
        $args['baseurl'] = $base_url;return $args;
    }
    add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'custom_upload_directory' );
```

[image: admin screen]

upon selecting a user from drop down i have to upload a file to his folder.

dropdown code

```
<div id="userlistdiv" >
    <form method="post" action="">
        <h2><?php echo "users: " ?></h2>
        <select id="userselection" name="userselection">
        <?php
            $blogusers = get_users('blog_id=1&orderby=login&role=subscriber');
            echo '<option value="" selected="selected"></option>';
            foreach ($blogusers as $user) {
                echo '<option>' . $user->user_login . '</option>';
            }
        ?>
        </select>
        <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use for your dropdown solution.

Comment: @criticalboot Always add code to questions with an [edit]. Never in a comment as this is unreadable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab a `WP_User` instance with [`get_user_by()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_user_by/) - [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by) documents that pretty well.

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'userLoginUploadDir' );
function userLoginUploadDir( $args )
{
    // Assuming that your forms user login (search? autocomplete? AJAX-ified? foo?) is named
    // name="user_login" id="user_login"
    $userLogin = esc_attr( $_GET['user_login'] );
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $userLogin );

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    return array_merge( $upload_dir, array(
        # 'path'    => '',
        # 'url'     => '',
        'subdir'  => $user->user_login,
        # 'basedir' => '',
        # 'baseurl' => '',
    ) );
}
```

Basically it should be enough to only set the specific `subdir` key. The rest should be available from [`wp_upload_dir()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir). In any case: Don't use constants for pathes or URLs/URIs. Use the functions as those are applying the needed filters.

Comment: for user it is working... as a admin i have a dropdown list of users. upon selecting a user from drop down i have to upload a document to that user... means i have to update subdir of upload_dir dynamically.

Comment: Please read the code in my answer in detail: It does all that. You just have to adjust it to retrieving the `user_login` value from your dropdown. And even for that an example/placeholder is given.

Comment: Hi Kaiser... I updated you code in line $userLogin = esc_attr( $_POST['userselection'] );  i am getting null in userLogin.

Comment: Do you get anything for `$_POST`. Btw, from here on it's quite off-topic and plain HTML form send and PHP retrieval. Please read about that on SO before we proceed.